# I have a problem in my timer app (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, timer

My flutter timer app is not working (not updating the time text widget) even though the implementation in @initState method is correct, as I think. I saw similar situations where the FutureBuilder is used. Am I supposed to do the same? Here is my code and please any help will be appreciated:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

//Some code here

class _Home extends State<Home> {
  static const Duration duration = Duration(seconds: 1);
  int hours = 0, minutes = 0, seconds = 0, secondsPassed = 0;
  bool isActive = false;
  Timer? timer;

  void start() {
    timer = Timer.periodic(duration, (Timer t) => handle());
  }

  void handle() {
    if (isActive) setState(() {
      secondsPassed = secondsPassed++;
      seconds = secondsPassed % 60;
      minutes = secondsPassed ~/ 60;
      hours = secondsPassed ~/ (60^2);
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    start();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Timer'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
            LabelText(hours.toString().padLeft(2, '0')),
            LabelText(minutes.toString().padLeft(2, '0')),
            LabelText(seconds.toString().padLeft(2, '0')),
      ]
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 60),
            Container(
              width: 200,
              height: 50,
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
              child: RaisedButton(
                child: Text(isActive ? 'Stop' : 'Start'),
                color: Colors.green,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)
                ),
                onPressed: () => setState(() => isActive = !isActive),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class LabelText extends StatelessWidget {
  //Some code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have defined isactive as false and checked isactive to be true in handle method.

Comment: Ok I will try to fix that.